# How to initialize nested array

Tags: java, arrays

How to initialize array with something like this

```
[1,'a',[2,'b',[3,'c']]]
```

I want to use arrays and not arraylist

Comment: array elements need to be the same type

Comment: @Steve Ideally that is the best case to have :) but  not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully what you want is an array of chars (and the integer values are just for our benefits to make it clearer), in which case you can do:

```
char[] arr = new char[] { 'a', new char[] { 'b', new char[] { 'c' } } };
```

If however for some reason you do want an array of mixed-types (which I strongly advise *against*, but I'm not aware of your usecase), you can do the same but with an array of Objects - you'll have to do type checks and casting for every single element access, be very very careful how you use this kind of array, it's very error-prone!:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[] { 1, 'a', new Object[] { 2, 'b', new Object[] { 3, 'c' } } };
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mlutiple types with in the array. Though it is not a good decision to have, but you can try the type as `Object`.

```
Object[] object = new Object[size];
```

In the above array you can insert another array also since it accepts of type Object(array is also an object after all).

Note: Be careful while retrieving the elements from array. You never know which type of object you are getting back.